# Mirror android screen to laptop using usb/wifi

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, meteor

I need to develop an app/web app for mirror android screen to the laptop through USB/wifi.

I am going to develop an app using react native for Android. I have few ideas about how I can achieve this like:-
1. Adb.
2. Root Access etc.

Please tell me the steps how I can achieve this.

Comment: Did you already research in the internet? Please do so and then come back when you have specific questions.

Comment: Yeah, I have already researched on the internet but unable to get a reliable answer.

Comment: this is wrong place to ask for steps to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you get started, you should split your project into small tasks and then continue research. Of course there is no complete tutorial for what you are looking for.

Tasks could be:

- Screen Recording
- Data transfer to laptop
- Playback of live video

This tasks could be then again splitted into small sub-tasks like:

**Screen Recording**

- How to capture screen shots/images
- How to combine them to a live sequence
- Which format to record and transfer...

**Data transfer to Laptop**

- Which communication medium to use? USB/WIFI/...
- Which protocol to use? TCP/...
- ...

And then split those sub-tasks to smaller tasks until they are clear and easy to handle. If you have any specific question about a specific task and researching the net does not help you, you of course may ask for help.